# I have updated flutter sdk version to 2.10.0 but in terminal error coming saying : current version is 2.8.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i have updated the sdk version of flutter to 2.10.0 but still old version (2.8.0) is showing in terminal due to which i am unable to use google fonts in my app as the google fonts require sdk version >=2.10.0. I Have used these two commands to upgrade - flutter upgrade and flutter pub get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for version file in flutter SDK. Open the flutter SDK folder and open the version file. It use to have a version specified, also check for the flutter version in VS Code at the bottom bar. If both are 2.10.0, then just flutter clean the project and rebuild. IF 2.8.0 is still there, download 2.10.0 zip file and unzip and replace the flutter SDK path.

Answer (score 1):

You would check your flutter's SDK version through the below command

```bash
flutter doctor -v
```

[image]
Once you type above command, the system will show you about the current config